# How do I display the category of a specific article I am displaying in Joomla?

Tags: joomla

I have created an alternative template for use in a module (Article Category NewsFlash). I am displaying three articles. One from each of three specific categories (I have more than three categories, but I only want to display from these three).

Newsflash allows me to select specific categories to look at - so this is not a problem.

I've setup the templates to look like the following:

```
<?php $images = json_decode($item->images);
$item_heading = $params->get('item_heading', 'h4'); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $item->link;?>">
<img width="130" height="82" src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro); ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_alt); ?>" />
</a>
<!--------------------------->
<h1>CHECK THE CATEGORY HERE</h1>
<!--------------------------->
<p class="valign" style="margin-top: 13px;">
<a class="gray" href="/reviews/bikes/kawasaki-adversys-versys-650-project">
    <-- The span below changes based on the category -->
            <span class="green fs12 db mb5">Latest Bike Review</span>
    <?php echo $item->title;?>
</a>
</p>
```

And it works perfectly. It displays three articles, inline horizontally, with the intro images displayed first followed by a line of text and then the title of the article.

My question is, how can I check the category of the current article? The code above is being looped through. I'm assuming it's something along the lines of `$item->category` but I can't quite seem to figure it out or find it anywhere.

Please help if you can!

> **Update:**

I ended up using a different module `mod_articles_category`. Using the default in this template I changed default.php to the following:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

?>
<div class="main sub-page" role="main">
<div class="header layout-img">
<p class="fl mt20">
<span class="yellow2 fs18">LATEST</span>
<br>
<span class="white fs14">REVIEWS</span>
</p>
<ul>
<?php
$mediafound = 0;
$gearfound = 0;
$bikefound = 0;
$currentitem = '';
foreach ($list as $item) :
$images = json_decode($item->images);
$item_heading = $params->get('item_heading', 'h4');

if(strpos($item->catslug, 'media') !== FALSE) {
    $mediafound = $mediafound + 1;
    $currentitem = 'media';
} elseif(strpos($item->catslug, 'gear') !== FALSE) {
    $gearfound = $gearfound + 1;
    $currentitem = 'gear';
} elseif(strpos($item->catslug, 'bike') !== FALSE) {
    $bikefound = $bikefound + 1;
    $currentitem = 'bike';
} ?>


<?php if($currentitem == 'media' && $mediafound == 1) { ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo $item->link;?>">
        <img width="130" height="82" src="<?php echo    htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro); ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_alt); ?>" />
    </a>
    <h1></h1>
    <p class="valign" style="margin-top: 13px;">
        <a class="gray" href="/reviews/bikes/kawasaki-adversys-versys-650-project">
                <span class="green fs12 db mb5">Latest Media Review</span>
            <?php echo $item->title;?>
        </a>
    </p>
    <span class="article-separator">&#160;</span>
</li>
<?php } elseif($currentitem == 'gear' && $gearfound == 1) { ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo $item->link;?>">
        <img width="130" height="82" src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro); ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_alt); ?>" />
    </a>
    <h1></h1>
    <p class="valign" style="margin-top: 13px;">
        <a class="gray" href="/reviews/bikes/kawasaki-adversys-versys-650-project">
            <span class="green fs12 db mb5">Latest Gear Review</span>
            <?php echo $item->title;?>
        </a>
    </p>
    <span class="article-separator">&#160;</span>
</li>
<?php } elseif($currentitem == 'bike' && $bikefound == 1) { ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo $item->link;?>">
        <img width="130" height="82" src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro); ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_alt); ?>" />
    </a>
    <h1></h1>
    <p class="valign" style="margin-top: 13px;">
        <a class="gray" href="/reviews/bikes/kawasaki-adversys-versys-650-project">
            <span class="green fs12 db mb5">Latest Bike Review</span>
            <?php echo $item->title;?>
        </a>
    </p>
    <span class="article-separator">&#160;</span>
</li>
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

This worked beautifully to display the the most recent article of three different categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified a Joomla version, but in 2.5+ the following is true, and may help.

The `$item` object in the `_item.php` template file contains the `catid` i.e. `$item->catid` is the ID of the category of the article in the current `$item`. This is an `int` value like `19`.

You can also get the `catslug` from `$item`, which is the category ID and *slug* (alias) concatenated together with a colon `:`  A typical `catslug` would be `19:joomla`.

Comment: I ended up having to use a different module for the exact specifications I wanted - but your comment was exactly what I needed to check for the specific category. Thank you so much!